# Error on Buy Button (Paypal Integration Gateway in CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I'm using a CodeIgniter 3 and I'm having a hard time on implementing the paypal integration on my website . For now I'm trying it on the sandbox and followed this tutorial [Paypal Integration Using CodeIgniter](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/)

Now the problem here is on my

**views/products/index.php**

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url().'products/buy/'.$product['id']; ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/x-click-but01.gif" style="width: 70px;">
 </a>
```

Now when i click the button **Paypal Buy Now** now it 
redirects me to

`products/buy/1 was not found on this server.`

I follow the instruction

and here is what on my database
[image]

Then i tried using the paypal button

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
       <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="S3RE65SMVGAHC">
       <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
       <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and it redirects me to paypal but without the prices that i inputted on my database. SOMEONE HELP ME PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
products/buy/1 was not found on this server.
```

is saying that the controller `Products.php` was not found.

Assuming the file is in the `applications/controllers' directory (it should be) then you need to make sure that the file name starts with an uppercase 'P'. In other words, the file name should be ***P***roducts.php not ***p***roducts.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try below sample codes.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR_ACCOUNT_EMAIL/MERCHANTID">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
</form>
```

And refer to below link for details of each variable.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/